# When I activate the shadow catcher in the plane it shows the hdri instead of showing just the shadow

Tags: transparency, shadows, reflection, shadowcatcher

When the shadow catcher is activated on the plane, it shows the envarioment instea[image]d of the other ground plane

follow new images to check it out

[image: follow new images to check it out]
[image: follow new images to check it out]

Comment: A shadow catcher works like a holdout object, everything occluded by it will be invisible to reveal the background. The difference to a holdout is, it shows shadows over the transparency. Now you might ask what to do if you want to see the plane below and I would answer, use different view layers for the floor and the shadow catcher and composite them together - but I would ask in return for clarification: a shadow catcher is used to composite shadow over a background like some footage and that's why it's transparent. Why use it when you have a visible floor plane that can receive the shadows?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I wanted to use the plane to create the shadow because on the existing surface the shadow is very weak and with a cut at the bottom as if there was some kind of error.and when I use the plane the shadow even improves, but when I activate the shadow catcher the problem I mentioned at the beginning occurs.

Comment: I also realized that this only happens inside this closed hangar. If I put sunlight in an open environment, the shade works normally.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoZvc.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoZvc.jpg)I disabled the hangar to notice that without it the shadow works normally. I have a slight impression that this all has to do with the lighting in the hangar, so I wanted to use a plane to recreate the shadow with I wanted.